# Linked list with memory allocation

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, bmp

I have a function that builds a linked list, and I'm trying to find the max and min coordinates of a bitmap file using the data in the list. Currently, it appears that the function for finding the center is unable to run due to a null pixel list. I suspect that the issue is with memory allocation.

```c
co_t* finding_center_cur(pix_t* pixel_list, int* h, int* w) // Finds the coordinates on the edges of each station using the linked list data.
{
   int max_x = -1, max_y = -1, min_x = *w, min_y = *h;
   int counter = 0; // Number of pixels in charger.
   pix_t* current = pixel_list;
   while (current != NULL) {
      if (max_x < current->x_y_cordinates.x) { // Finds the largest X coordinate in the station.
         max_x = current->x_y_cordinates.x;
      }
      if (max_y < current->x_y_cordinates.y) { // Finds the largest Y coordinate in the station.
         max_y = current->x_y_cordinates.y;
      }
      if (min_x > current->x_y_cordinates.x) { // Finds the smallest X coordinate in the station.
         min_x = current->x_y_cordinates.x;
      }
      if (min_y > current->x_y_cordinates.y) { // Finds the smallest Y coordinate in the station.
         min_y = current->x_y_cordinates.y;
      }
      current = current->next;
   }
   co_t* CENTER = malloc(sizeof(co_t)); // Allocates memory for CENTER pointer.
   CENTER->x = round((max_x + min_x) / 2); // Calculates and rounds the X coordinate.
   CENTER->y = round((max_y + min_y) / 2); // Calculates and rounds the Y coordinate.
   return CENTER;
}
```

Comment: "is unable to run" It isn't clear what you mean by that. Please share what you directly observe (for example, *a message that says "Segmentation fault, core dumped"*), not what you deduce from the unknown set of observations.

Comment: Memory allocation for such a small `O(1)` thing is likely to be inefficient, maybe `co_t finding_center_cur` to allocate it on the stack.